# How to solve unresolved superstypes

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I didn't manage to find a direct solution to this issue. I added a fragment class and layout to my project and it started showing this issue during execution.

The error states, 
"Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the right dependencies in the classpath: class androidx.app.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivty, unresolved supertypes: androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable".

I have attached my gradle file contents.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mapp.com.sg.mappfinalassignment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.+'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.+'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'


}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

How do I get it to run?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use new AndroidX dependencies with the old ones. You can try to run `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` in your Android studio or convert you dependencies manually. Here is the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) which will help you.